# Deploy Django project to a website subfolder

Tags: mysql, django, apache, production, mode

I have a website (e.x. www.example.com), and a web server and my goal is to upload a Django project (already completed at my home pc) into a subfolder of my example website. That is, I would like my django project to run at www.example.com/mynewdjango/. The web server runs Apache and MySql. My project uses Mysql too.
Is there a step by step guide to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can start from:

[This step by step Guide](https://coderwall.com/p/ooerda/python-django-apache-ubuntu)

[Official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Comment: Thank you, maybe this will help but as I mentioned I do not want to start a new django site in the remote web server, but to transfer a finished app in a subfolder of a website. Your guide starts a new django app. I don t know if this is a different situation